# So I want to restart nodejs server at crash

Tags: node.js, nodemon, forever

So I want to restart nodejs server at crash. I run scripts with this command.

```
nodemon -r esm app.js
```

I tried with forever but somehow not able to find the right command to pack "nodemon -r esm app.js" and add restart feature at crash.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the standard you need to support both nodemon and [Forever.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) for this.

```
forever start -c "nodemon -r esm --harmony" app.js --exitcrash
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I add ECMAScript 6 modules support? I do this with node -r esm app.js but how to do with forever? well I need nodemon because it can restart at file change(example when I modify)

Comment: Thanks. Script runs without errors but doesn't execute anything. it should execute 1 with console.log if I run node -r esm app.js if I run with your way it just stops without any output.

Comment: This is the sample code I use with nodemon -r esm app.js -->import {something} from './test';
let x=1; console.log(x) and it doesn't work with the updated method. Also there is needed another file test.js with this code for example: "let something=0;
export{something}" and only my current method works for those.

Answer (score 0):

You can try PM2 or running nodejs app using systemd

```
[Unit]
Description=app.js
Documentation=https://example.com
After=network.target

[Service]
Environment=NODE_PORT=3001
Type=simple
User=ubuntu
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /home/ubuntu/app.js
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

[PM2:](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) `pm2 start app.js`

Comment: Thanks! I use windows 10. I think it's for linux